# OLAP datasets other than Adventureworks?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I'm looking to play around with various cube data to better understand it. I've also created a few of my own to play around with, but it's quite tedious to do, especially with saving the tables/views into the cube.

Other than [`Adventure Works`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-adventureworks), are there any data sets that I can download to play around with? I've been having a hard time finding any of these via Google, MSDN, etc. I'm open to whatever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this github [link](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases) you will find 2 sample databases other than  `Adventure Works` wich are

1. wide-world-importers.
2. contoso-data-warehouse.

Comment: Thanks -- are there any backup files for this? Otherwise, it seems like I have to install everything from scratch which is a much bigger pain that just using the .bk file for AdventureWorks which makes it so simple.

Comment: @BOURBIT -- I was able to get the wide-world-importers working! How were you able to get the contoso one working?